# snap to div on scroll and button click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I searched for a jquery that snaps on the next div with full height when scrolling. The scroll to div is successful when the buttons are clicked. But when I scroll using the mouse wheel it doesn't snap to the next div. I tried a jquery from a tutorial and it works on my screen but the height is declared in px so if I changed to mobile view the snap is incorrect. Here is the code.

```
<a id="panel1div"></a>
<a id="panel2div"></a>
<a id="panel3div"></a>
<a id="panel4div"></a>
<header class="nav">
    <nav class="buttons">
        <ul class="button-holder">
            <li><a href="#panel1div">•</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#panel2div">•</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#panel3div">•</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#panel4div">•</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<section id="paneldivs">
    <article class="panel1 panels" id="servicios">
        <h1> Nuestros Servicios</h1>
    </article>

    <article class="panel2 panels" id="galeria">
        <h1> Mustra de nuestro trabajos</h1>
    </article>

    <article class="panel3 panels" id="contacto">
        <h1> Pongamonos en contacto</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="panel4 panels" id="contacto">
        <h1> Pongamonos en contacto</h1>
    </article>
</section>

<style>
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: none;
}

h1 {
    padding: 50vh 0;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.buttons {
    width: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.button-holder {
    height: 100vh;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.buttons a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #000;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a[ id= "panel1div" ]:target ~ #paneldivs article.panels {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
    transform: translateY( 0px );
}

a[ id= "panel2div" ]:target ~ #paneldivs article.panels {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -100vh );
    transform: translateY( -100vh );
}
a[ id= "panel3div" ]:target ~ #paneldivs article.panels {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -200vh );
    transform: translateY( -200vh );
}
a[ id= "panel4div" ]:target ~ #paneldivs article.panels {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -300vh );
    transform: translateY( -300vh );
}

.panels {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0 );
  transform: translateZ( 0 );
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.panel1 {
    background: #ccc;
}

.panel2 {
    background: #ff0;
}

.panel3 {
    background: #ddd;
}

.panel4 {
    background: #0ff;
}
</style>
<script>
var scrolling = false;

$(document).on("wheel mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
  if (!scrolling) {
  var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (e.type === "mousewheel" || e.type === "wheel") {
    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
      down = true;
    } else {
      down = false;
    }
  } else if (e.type === "DOMMouseScroll") {
    if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
      down = true;
    } else {
      down = false;
    }
  } else if (e.type === "keyup") {
          var keycode = e.originalEvent.keyCode;
          if (keycode === 40 || keycode === 32 || keycode === 34) { //down, space, pgdwn
            down = true;
          } else if (keycode === 38 || keycode === 33) { //up, pgup
            down = false;
          } else if (keycode === 35) { //end
            down = 2;
          } else if (keycode === 36) { //home
            down = 3;
          } else {
            return;
          }
        } else {
    return;
  }
  var destination = scroll;
  if (down && scroll !== 947 * 3) {
    destination = Math.floor((destination + 947) / 947) * 947;
  } else if (!down && scroll !== 0) {
    destination = Math.ceil((destination - 947) / 947) * 947;
  } else {
    return;
  }
    scrolling = true;
  $("html, body").stop().animate({
    scrollTop: destination
  }, function() {
    scrolling = false;
  });
  }
})
</script>
```

Please help me fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Just try to get height of screen on page load and use that height instead of using fixed height. You will also have to make other pivot points dynamic as well.

Comment: Can you provide a jquery for that?

Comment: You can get width and height of window using these functions https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

Comment: I don't know how to implement that in my code. I'm really not familiar with jquery. :'(